# CSS Target Attribute Containing Partial Match

Tags: html, css, match, selector, partial

Using the following CSS, why am I not able to target the 3 following anchor tags?

```
a[href~="checkout"] { /* Do something. */ }

<a href="http://shop.mydomain.com/checkout/onepage/">
<a href="https://shop.mydomain.com/checkout/onepage/">
<a href="https://shop.mydomain.com/checkout/onepage/?___SID=S">
```

What am I doing wrong in my CSS selector? I'm trying to select a partial match using ~= for all URLs containing the word "checkout."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
a[href*="checkout"] { /* Do something. */ }
```

You have to use *, which means *contain* - see [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp).

Also, don't forget to close anchor tags

```
</a>
```

Working [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hpq9ykzk/)

Comment: Then what is ~= used for?

Comment: You use ~= if containing a specific word. I.e. a[class~="checkout"] when <a class="link green checkout"></a>

Answer (score 4):

```
a[href~="checkout"]
```

matches elements where in a whitespace-separated list of words one of these is exactly "checkout".

See W3C Docs for Selectors Level 3:

> **[*att*~=val]**
>
> Represents an element with the *att* attribute whose value is
>   a whitespace-separated list of words, one of which is exactly "val".
>   If "val" contains whitespace, it will never represent anything (since
>   the words are separated by spaces). Also if "val" is the empty string,
>   it will never represent anything.
>
> Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors

If you want to match all elements where *attr* **contains** *string*, use

```
[attr*=string]
```